# Shared singleton instance

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am implementing a program which uses a *shared* utility class with singleton behavior.

One instance of the utility class is created in the main thread and passed to all other objects instantiated:

```
SomeUtil util = new SomeUtil();

...

Foo foo = new Foo(util, arg1, arg2)
Bar bar = new Bar(util, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

Is there some more elegant way of achiving this (i.e. design pattern)?

Comment: you have given the answer..use  Singlton pattern. !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Singleton can be an alternative. Note though that your current design is easy to unit test (since you are injecting the `SomeUtil` dependency, which can thus easily be replaced by a mock object during unit tests), while Singleton makes unit testing awkward and difficult:

- it makes your objects depend on global state, thus it is more difficult to setup your tests correctly, and easy to make mistakes (e.g. by forgetting to initialize the Singleton properly for a specific test),
- it is more difficult to understand the code since you can't easily identify whether or not a given piece of code is dependent on global state, except by actually reading the whole code.

That being said, if it is a real utility class, i.e. it has no internal state, and it is not dependent on anything which would make unit testing difficult (like a DB, or file system), it can be OK to use it as a Singleton (although this begs the question why do you need to instantiate it at all - usually utility classes have only static methods, and a private constructor to prevent instantiation).

Comment: Yes, the utility class should be stateless, so it might be possible to implement as a true Singleton or as a static class.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you pass around utility object? The SomeUtil can have static methods, so that the methods in Foo and bar can use it.

Also, you can implement an actual singleton pattern.

Comment: +1. Utility classes should strive to be static, with the implied contract of being stateless (ie thread-safe) in addition.

Comment: @pap: statelessness implies thread safety, but they are not at all the same concept.  You can have thread safety with a stateful object.

Comment: @Mark: They sure can and I did not mean to imply otherwise. I highlighted the thread-safe quality of statelessness as it is a primary concern of utility classes. Replace "ie" with "and thusly" in my previous comment for increased clarity :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could actually use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which typically stores a static reference to the single instance in the class itself.

```
public class SomeUtil {
    private static final SomeUtil instance = new SomeUtil();
    public static SomeUtil getInstance() { 
        return instance;
    }
    //...
}
```

Doing this can make things less unit testable however, so be aware.  It's typically much easier to break an injected dependency than a global one.

Comment: The SomeUtil class is implemented as you described, but it was never fully utilized as a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have an actual singleton? Much nicer than passing a single instance around everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the nicest way to get around this is add/use some Dependency Injection framework.

- framework will guarantee the object indeed is singleton (which has been traditionally a bit tricky especially when done in lazy fashion)
- you can substitute/control the singleton 'instance' when testing
- you can get rid off singleton-passed-as-constructor-parameter (if you want to)